# CSS3: Background URL issues

Tags: html, css

Background img for a div is not displaying. Using FireFox dev tool and it says the image could not be loaded. But if I link to the image using an img tag it works fine. I would rather display the image in css using the background property. For my file structure I have an img, css and js folder nested inside my project folder. Is there something wrong with the path since i'm in a css folder trying to link to a file in another folder?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.container {
  
}
.hero {
 background: url('img/15827396293_fc1e0f749d_o%20(2).jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="hero">
         <h1> This is a test</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try changing the path for your url to: background: url('./img/15827396293_fc1e0f749d_o%20(2).jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;

Comment: Try '../img/15827396293_fc1e0f749d_o%20(2).jpg' since I suppose you are including a file from another folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in your css folder, it is looking for `css/img/file.jpg`.  If you wan't to keep with relative paths, you will need to change your image path to `../img/file.jpg`.  I would recommend the use of absolute paths, but that is up to you. With an absolute path, you don't have to worry about if you accidentally forgot your ellipses.

Comment: Thanks. You were spot on!

Answer (score -1):

Try ".." to move up a document tree

```
.hero {
    background: url('../img/15827396293_fc1e0f749d_o%20(2).jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```